# Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'admin/projects/projectssCategory/list'

Tags: angular, web-frontend, angular-routerlink

I am getting this error repeatedly, for one and another module.

```
ListProjectCategoryRoutingModule
```

Looks like:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthGuard } from '../../../../../helpers/auth.gaurd';
import { Role } from '../../../../../data/schema/role';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { ListProjectCategoryComponent } from './list-project-category.component';

const routes: Routes = [{ path: 'admin/projects/projectCategory/list', 
component: ListProjectCategoryComponent 
//canActivate: [AuthGuard],
//data: { roles: [Role.Admin]}
}];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ListProjectCategoryRoutingModule { }


ListProjectCategoryComponent
```

Looks like:

```
import { DetailsProjectCategoryComponent } from '../details-project-category/details-project-category.component';
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { ProjectsCategoryService } from "../../../../../data/service/projectsCategory.service";
import { ProjectsCategory } from "../../../../../data/schema/projects";
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: "app-list-project-category",
  templateUrl: "./list-project-category.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./list-project-category.component.css"]
})
export class ListProjectCategoryComponent implements OnInit {
  projectsCategory: Observable<ProjectsCategory[]>;

  constructor(private projectsCategoryService: ProjectsCategoryService,
    private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.reloadData();
  }

  reloadData() {
    this.projectsCategory = this.projectsCategoryService.getProjectsCategorysList();
  }

  deleteProjectsCategory(id: number) {
    this.projectsCategoryService.deleteProjectsCategory(id)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          console.log(data);
          this.reloadData();
        },
        error => console.log(error));
  }

  // employeeDetails(id: number){
  //   this.router.navigate(['details', id]);
  //}
}
```

I called it it from html file, `Home`, `Admin`, `Projects` pages are navigating properly but i am getting error in `ProjectCategory` page

```
<div *ngIf="isAdmin">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark" *ngIf="user">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" routerLink="/admin/home">Home</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" routerLink="/admin" *ngIf="isAdmin">Admin</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" routerLink="/admin/projects">Projects</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" routerLink="/admin/projects/projectssCategory/list">List Project Category</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" (click)="logout()">Logout</a>
    </div>
</nav>
</div>
```

I have to add more modules similar to `ListProjectCategory`

Have added their route in `app.routing.ts` and it is working fine for other modules

> { path: '', loadChildren: () =>
> import('./modules/admin/project-folder/projectCategory/list-project-category/list-project-category.module').then(m
> => m.ListProjectCategoryModule) },

Comment: share  your approuting code also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have path

```
routerLink="/admin/projects/projectssCategory/list"
```

But routes expect

```
admin/projects/projectCategory/list
```

Just merge expect and real results

I think problem with projectssCategory where double s

Answer (score 1):

in app routing routes . In moduler architecture as route you should give base path such as admin. If you have second module  then you can have problems with empty base route.

```
{ path: 'admin', loadChildren: () => import('./modules/admin/project-folder/projectCategory/list-project-category/list-project-category.module').then(m => m.ListProjectCategoryModule) }
```

in module routing

```
const routes: Routes = [{ path: 'projects/projectCategory/list', 
component: ListProjectCategoryComponent 
//canActivate: [AuthGuard],
//data: { roles: [Role.Admin]}
}];
```

and be sure that correct link you gave

in html call `/admin/projects/projectCategory/list` in `routerLink`